# Installing Drupal 8.2.4 - Clean URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

So I have attempted to install Drupal 8.2.4 onto a dedicated server that I own.

I am running WampServer 3.0.4 64-bit with PHP 5.6.19 and MySQL 5.7.11.

I successfully get through the installation wizard and to the main page of the website however when I try to go to various pages, none of them work.

This appears to be an issue with Clean URLs. During the installation I get a warning message that Clean URLs is not enabled.

However, I have checked my apache config and rewrite_mod is enabled.

I tried to manually access the admin page @ ?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls however it just returns me to the index page.

I've taken a look over the guide here: https://www.drupal.org/node/15365

I tred modifying my httpd.conf by adding the following to the bottom:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mms-beta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

However, then the server won't start.

I've also ensured that for /www/ the AllowOverride is set to All for the purposes of htaccess.

Can someone give me an idea as to what I need to do to get this to work?

**UPDATE**: So I tried adding garbage to my .htaccess file and it doesn't break, so its clear my htaccess file is not even being read.

Comment: you mean the snippet you put is in .htaccess  - this looks like an .htaccess file? Depending on where you put the rewrite rules, it wont allow your server to come up. I would look at the apache error logs, it will be verbose about what is wrong, which line it does not like

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

You need to add an alias under Apache through the wamp tray icon and then modify the conf file.

In the conf file specify as follows:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then delete:

```
require local
```

Now htaccess will work correctly.